# lambda operator c# learning

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Can you recommend me on places where i can read and see examples on usage of Lambda operator in c# .

I will really like to see a lot examples on it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is several tutorials about lambdas:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/Lambda-Expressions.aspx

And here are Eric Lippert's posts on the subject:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Lambda+Expressions/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Apart from a search on Google, I'd probably recommend getting the free version of [CodeRush / Refactor! from DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/).  One of the refactorings is to convert code to lambda expressions, and can be an excellent way to see real-world, relevant examples based on your own code.

Edit: The Lambda Refactorings that come with CodeRush Xpress are [detailed here](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/lambda.xml)

Comment: Can you put me a link to it i just can't see it on their page...

Comment: try http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Answer (score 2):

Eric White has a nice blog entry on some examples of Lambda expressions:

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/Lambda-Expressions.aspx
```

Otherwise, as each expressions is generally bespoke to the requirement I'd advise a decent book to get you started. Many of the Linq title cover lambda expressions well. Personally I'd recommend [Linq in Action](http://linqinaction.net/)

Comment: +1 for LINQ in Action, section 2.4, page 55.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet wrote an excellent book that tackles lambda expressions but also goes into a tremendous amount of depth on topics that might be new to someone coming from a C# 1 or 2 background. http://csharpindepth.com/

Answer (score 0):

Two other good introductions to C# lambda expressions:

- [Explaining C# lambda statements in one sentence (and LINQ in about 10)](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/04/explaining-c-lambda-statements-in-one-sentence-and-linq-in-about-10.html)
- [LINQ in Action](http://linqinaction.net/)

The first (disclaimer - my blog) will give you a quick explanation of the fundamental concepts. The book provides complete coverage of all relevant topics.